# How can I get the error stacktrace out of a message put on the error queue by NServiceBus?

Tags: error-handling, nservicebus

When a message gets moved to the error queue by nservicebus, how can I get the exception details (message, stacktrace, etc) out of the message?  Is there a tool that I can get that with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those details are stored in the extension of the message so you need a tool the can display the extension. Queue explorer is one tool that a lot of people use,